# Can I use Win apps on Win IoT on RPi3?

Tags: pi-3, windows-iot

I had planned to use Pi-3 to run some chartplotter (sea version of SatNav) software. The software works in linux but the charts only work for windows! If I installed Win-IoT will this work the same as Windows on PC? That is, will I be able to load the software and run it in the same way?

Comment: A word of warning: Win 10 IoT core differs quite much from "desktop" windows. It's highly likely that any kind of software will not run as is. Lets call that a [*reduced feature set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Comparison_chart).

Comment: @Matt i think it is possible but its only on Raspbian try "wine" emulator! Heres how to do that [YouTube Video [Play]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZuV8oTZiQE)